# Redirect user to Django 500 error page from function instead of view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django view that looks for a variable in the user's session and, if it can't find it, raises a 500 error and redirects the user to my custom 'project/templates/500.html' page.

```
# views.py
def process_country(request, template):
    try:
        country = request.session['country']
    except KeyError as e:
        msg = "Key %s not found for uid %s" % ('country', request.user.id)
        log.error(msg, exc_info=True)
        return render(request, '500.html', status=500)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # do stuff...
        pass
    else:
        form = MyForm(initial={'country': country})
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This view works as intended if the 'country' session variable doesn't exist.  However, what I'd like to do is move this ugly block of exception handling code to a helper function:

```
# views.py
from utils import get_from_session
def process_country(request, template):
    country = get_from_session(request, 'country')  # Helper
    if request.method == "POST":
        # do stuff...
        pass
    else:
        form = MyForm(initial={'country': country})
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)

# utils.py
from django.shortcuts import render
def get_from_session(request, key):
    try:
        value = request.session[key]
        return value
    except KeyError as e:
        msg = "Key %s not found for uid %s" % (key, request.user.id)
        log.error(msg, exc_info=True)
        # Neither of these work!
        #return render(request, '500.html', status=500)
        #render(request, '500.html')
```

The problem is that in this second version, the user doesn't get redirected to the custom 500.html error page.  Instead, Django displays the template passed to the process_country view but it embeds the raw HTML contained in the 500.html page in that template.  I guess I could do an HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('500-page')) but that would entail creating a view and it doesn't feel like the right solution.  What's going on here?  Can I redirect the user to the custom 500.html template from a function and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Raise an error this display 500.html in production automaticaly

```
raise KeyError
```

But this wrong way, you should never raise exceptions for user. Instead this you may checks `country` in your view and if it's not exists, for example, display some message for user in template.